# Fragment shader in LibGDX for tiled water texture

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shader, fragment-shader

Using LibGDX, I am trying to figure out how to write a simple fragment shader that is able to render a tiled water texture using a simple sine effect in both the X and Y directions, but making sure adjacent tiles are still connected on the texture edge (see picture). I'm having a hard time figuring this simple thing out - my maths might be a little bit rusty. Can you help me?

[image: Example of the problem - not seamless connections]

Of course, the shader cannot "guess" what's on the negative part of the texture when the texture coordinates are offset inwards, but the texture is a self-connecting mosaic, so I guess something can be done here.

The fragment shader is:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;    // 0
uniform float time;             // elapsed time
uniform float xFactor;          // controls effect amplitude in the X and Y directions
uniform float yFactor;
uniform float xWobble;          // de-synchronize X and Y 'wobling' effect between layers
uniform float yWobble;

const float M_PI = 3.1415926538;

varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main()
{
    vec2 l_texCoords = v_texCoords;
    l_texCoords = v_texCoords + vec2(xFactor * sin((1. - v_texCoords.x) * 2. * M_PI + time * xWobble), yFactor * cos((1. - v_texCoords.y) * 2. * M_PI + time * yWobble));
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, l_texCoords);

}
```

Then, in the Java side, I do:

```
batch.setShader(waterShader);
batch.setProjectionMatrix(backgroundCamera1.combined); //Background 1
batch.begin();
batch.getShader().setUniformf("time", deltaAcc);
batch.getShader().setUniformf("xFactor", 0.05f);
batch.getShader().setUniformf("yFactor", 0.07f);
batch.getShader().setUniformf("xWobble", 0.12f);
batch.getShader().setUniformf("yWobble", 0.22f);
batchTileMapRenderer.setView(backgroundCamera1);
bTileMapRenderer.renderTileLayer(tilesBg1Layer); // The water layer, with 128x128 tiles
batch.end();
batch.setShader(null);
```

I hope you can shed some light on this apparently simple problem...

Comment: Is the repeatable image a texture region in an atlas, or the entire texture?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Each tile is a region of the same texture. More or less I solved the problem for a specific case, but when the sine is made dependent on the varying u_textureCoord in the following way: `float x_offset = sin(time + (5.0*u_textureCoord.x + 5.0*u_textureCoord.y) * FACTOR)` and I do the same for y, the moment FACTOR is different from 1.0, the tiles at the edge of the texture don't line up. There must be a way to pass in a uniform with some phase information maybe, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: You won’t be able to batch draw them if you do it this way because SpriteBatch doesn’t have enough vertex data to hold information about where to jump the UVs back to repeat them. You would have to set up some shader uniforms that are different for each different tile you draw. At that point you might as well not put them in an atlas and then it would be easy to have them automatically repeat seamlessly.